# How to put query data in two different arrays then echo it in two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

Run `select query` on `table`

filter the query data

if its `gender equal to Man`, then put all of his in array men=array()

OR

if its `gender is woman` then put in array woman=array()

then `echo` two tables

`Men` Table

1-Name, age, city, country, etc

2-Name, age, city, country, etc

3-Name, age, city, country, etc
.
.
.

`Women` Table

1-Name, age, city, country, etc

2-Name, age, city, country, etc

3-Name, age, city, country, etc
.
.
.
.

`Men` table will contain all rows data of `Man` which are save in `Men()` array

`Women` table will contain all rows data of `Woman` which are save in `Women()` array

Note:-

I have tried code like this but its mess and i failed:-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38653118/notice-undefined-offset-1-putting-mysql-query-data-in-while-loop

Comment: edit prevous question dont ask again

Comment: Why are you separating women from men (sounds funny)? Add a gender column (i would put int because reasons like https://40.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lhdwd8xxRj1qak0xgo1_500.jpg )

Comment: give your code to check

Comment: and there are more than 2 genders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query must be in `UNION`:

```
Select men.Name, men.age, men.city, men.country, 'Male' as 'gender' FROM men_table as men UNION ALL Select women.Name, women.age, women.city, women.country, 'Female' as 'gender FROM women_table as women;
```

so you can have an query output:

```
|Name   |age    |city   |country|gender|
----------------------------------------
|male1  |21     |NY     |USA    |Male  |
|male2  |23     |CLV    |USA    |Male  |
|female1|25     |GS     |USA    |Female|
|female2|27     |CHG    |USA    |Female|
```

after that you can loop to your result:

```
<?php 

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
    $query = "Select men.Name, men.age, men.city, men.country, 'Male' as 'gender' FROM men_table as men UNION ALL Select women.Name, women.age, women.city, women.country, 'Female' as 'gender FROM women_table as women";

    $men = array();
    $women = array;

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

        /* fetch associative array */
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if($row["gender"] == 'Male') {
                $men[] = $row[];
            }
            else {
                $women[] = $row[];
            }
        }

        print_r($men);
        print_r($women);

        /* free result set */
        $result->free();
    }

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

The output will be like:

```
//$men array
    array(
        [0] => array(
                'Name' => 'male1', 
                'age' => '21', 
                'city' => 'NY', 
                'country' => 'USA', 
                'gender' => 'Male'
        ),
        [1] => array(
                'Name' => 'male2', 
                'age' => '23', 
                'city' => 'CLV', 
                'country' => 'USA', 
                'gender' => 'Male'
        )
    );

//$women array
    array(
        [0] => array(
                'Name' => 'female1', 
                'age' => '25', 
                'city' => 'GS', 
                'country' => 'USA', 
                'gender' => 'Female'
        ),
        [1] => array(
                'Name' => 'female2', 
                'age' => '27', 
                'city' => 'CHG', 
                'country' => 'USA', 
                'gender' => 'Female'
        )
    );
```

Comment: you marked me first then remove it. why? can i know the reason?

Comment: @Anant yup I noticed that he marked you first. maybe because of the query? because he said earlier that he has 2 tables `men` and `women` so maybe he is looking for a `JOIN` query. IDK my speculations maybe wrong

Comment: I think that his data is in `one table` and he want to fetch data differently and want to show it like `men table(html table)` and `women table(html table)`. No offense if it's the case what you described.

Comment: I am a bit confused on how he state his problem though. I don't know how he wanted for us to solve his problem. this post kinda lacks of data. None taken lad @Anant.

Comment: His question heading is totally reverse what he selected as an answer.

Comment: maybe he wanted to insert the array into two different tables haha IDK lad I am confused right now.